# While getting large amount of data from POST call, it loads in browser but shows failed to load response data in chrome inspect element response body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

There is a post api call which is called and it renders data on the UI but when i tried to see it in the inspect element response and preview tabs i get this error "failed to load response data". The array returned contains 7000 objects and each object has 80 key-value pairs. if i reduce the data which is returned with that call then it works fine.
What can be the issue with the large amount of data.

Comment: When would you ever need 7000 results in a single request in the UI? Use pagination.

Comment: Yes i agree. Pagination should be used. But in this case I dont want to use pagination.